# Qual è il significato di "avere le gambe corte"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, proverbs

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> «Signorina, stia bene attenta a non dir bugie. Le bugie, con noi, **hanno le gambe corte**. E chi dice le bugie durante un interrogatorio, lo sa dove va a finire?» e la 
>   guardò di nuovo fisso, ma lei ormai si era ripresa e sostenne intrepida il suo sguardo.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire che "le bugie hanno le gambe corte" in questo brano. 
Si tratta di un modo di dire? L'ho cercato nel Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli, ma non l'ho trovato. Mi potreste spiegare qual è il suo significato?

Comment: ... e il naso lungo

Comment: Aggiungerei che le bugie sono anche quei bassi sostegni per le candele (corti, appunto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si intende che cercando di cavarsela con le bugie “non si va lontano”, cioè che chi mente prima o poi si tradisce o viene scoperto. «Le bugie hanno le gambe corte» è una frase fatta così com'è e risulta già per esempio nel [*Dizionario della lingua italiana*](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ag1aAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA146&dq=le+bugie+hanno+le+gambe+corte&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true) (per cura di Paolo Costa e Francesco Cardinali) del 1820:

> Si dice parimenti per proverb[io] Le bugie hanno le gambe corte; e significa, che presto si scuopre la verità. *Lat.* falsum continuo palam est.

Comment: E sempre si usa con la parola "bugie" o si può usare con un altro vocabolo? Cioè, non sono le persone che dicono bugie quelle che hanno le gambe corte?

Comment: Completo la risposta.